How to check, if a given FPNode in selection dag in llvm has FTZ attribute?
Hi thanks for looking into this, I want to check given a Selection-DAG FP Node, how to check if it has FTZ (flush to zero) attribute, For one I already check if the target has denormals, if yes then I flush it to zero. But how to check for explicit ftz attribute if any. I assume it would be part of fast-math flags, but it is not apparent to me how to check in code? Any APIs or links/Code I can take a look at?
Already checking for denormal as follows.
ConstantFPSDNode *CFP = ...

const APFloat &C = CFP->getValueAPF();
if (C.isDenormal()) {
    EVT VT = Node->getValueType(0);
    DenormalMode Mode =
        CurDAG->getMachineFunction().getDenormalMode(C.getSemantics());
    if (Mode == DenormalMode::getPreserveSign()) {
      SDValue Zero =  CurDAG->getConstantFP(0.0, dl, VT);
      ReplaceNode(Node,Zero.getNode());
      SelectCode(Zero.getNode());
      return;
    }
  }

Expect to check explicit ftz attribute or a condition that states this.
